# Submit button is upper than looping table input field

Tags: php, for-loop, html-table

I have got in trouble when I was going to show (print is more suitable) a list of input field within `form`.
According to normal situation, there will be a Submit button below it in order to submit the form to (any pages).

Then, I was so confused., because when I use this below code to loop.

```
<table>
<form>
for($a=1; $a<=10; $a++){
  <tr>
    <td>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name<? echo $a; ?>" required="required"/>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="form-group">
           <input  class="form-control" type="text" name="url<? echo $a; ?>" required="required"/>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
</form>
</table>
```

Tadaa...then it shows:
[image]

And the Submit button is on the top of the form?!
Can any help me to fix it?

Or...at least some reason?

Comment: Please show your actual code

Comment: and make your question more clear.whats *Submit button is upper than looping input field* mean?

Comment: Your `table` tag is missing.

Comment: put the `<table>` tag before the form like `<form><table></table><input></form>`

Comment: @MarkVincentManjac Yes, is it.

Comment: @JonP Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Sorry for the misleading and broken title, I've tried to change it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your code like

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
   </td>
</tr>
```

it will display submit button below the input field.

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrect order of html tags.

```
<table>
    <form>
        <tr>
        ...
        </tr>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
    </form>
</table>
```

`<table>` tag can only [contain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table) (in this particular order)

- an optional `<caption>` element,
- zero or more `<colgroup>` elements,
- an optional `<thead>` element,
- either one of the following:

  - zero or more `<tbody>` elements
  - one or more `<tr>` elements
- an optional `<tfoot>` element

---

Try reordering your elements like this:

```
<form>
    <table>
        <tr>
        ...
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
</form>
```